# Trying to get mod_rewrite rule to work

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get an htaccess rewrite rule working and not having any luck. I've gone through a couple tutorials and can get redirects working, but not rewrite (which is what I need).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I want users to enter this URL:

```
http://example.com/sample-article
```

Actual page content:

```
http://example.com/live-site/testing-2012/article-123/
```

My htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/sample-article$ http://example.com/live-site/testing-2012/article-123/ [NC,L]
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the leading `/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sample-article$ /live-site/testing-2012/article-123/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: That got it going in the right direction, I think. The final page is in a WordPress install and I got a 404, but from the WP site, so at least in the right area. I tried changing the second URL to the /?p=123 format and I then got to the right page, but it redirected rather then rewrote.
But if I change my target to another page, outside WordPress, I get what I want, so this is the right answer for my question. Thanks for your assistance Qtax.